# How to close app page if body with two Scaffold

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I was using this line to close page   `Navigator.pop(context);` but in this case it showing black screen and i tried to call   `Navigator.pop(context);` 2 times but black page still there. What to do here?
My page code code

```
import 'package:appname/GradientAppBar.dart';
import 'package:appname/bizutil/bill_card.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BookingHistory extends StatefulWidget {
  BookingHistory({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BookingHistoryState createState() => _BookingHistoryState();
}

class _BookingHistoryState extends State<BookingHistory> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home:
      Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(child: GradientAppBar(popCount:2),preferredSize: Size(double.infinity, 100),),
        body:    DefaultTabController(
            length: 3,
            child: Scaffold(
              // backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              appBar: AppBar(
                flexibleSpace: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TabBar(
                          indicatorColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                          tabs: [
                            Tab(
                              child: Text(
                                "Completed",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Tab(
                              child: Text(
                                "Requested",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Tab(
                              child: Text(
                                "Accepted",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                              ),
                            )
                          ])

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              body: TabBarView(children: [
                Container(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 5,
                      itemBuilder: (context,index){
                    return BillCard();
                  }),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 10,
                      itemBuilder: (context,index){
                        return BillCard();
                      }),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 20,
                      itemBuilder: (context,index){
                        return BillCard();
                      }),
                ),
              ]),
            )),
      )


    );
  }
}
```

Here GradientAppBar is a StatelessWidget

Comment: do you want to close the app ? or an activity ?

Comment: only close that activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project should declare `MaterialApp` only once, basically in `main.dart` file.

remove the `MaterialApp` Widget from build() method.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(....)
```

to

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(...)
```

*If it worked for you, please mark the solution to accepted by clicking the **Correct Tick** icon.*

Comment: Okay, great my issue fixed and i will accept your answer tomorrow bez it need few minutes to accept answer